# Database search returns inconsistent results

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm running a simple database search against one table in my database. The results are then displayed in a table.  If no results are found, the search shows a message that says `"0 results"`, but sometimes it will echo the table headings without displaying any results. This search is part of a class project and isn't going to be an active database, so I haven't included any protection for SQL injection. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<h2>Customer Search</h2>
<br>
<p class="first">Search the Customer Database</p>

<form action="searchcustomers.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search...." />
  <input type="submit" value=">>" />
</form>

<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "oldga740_SeniorProject";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


// If there is a search variable try to search database
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Client LIKE '%$searchq%'";

if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

     echo '<table class="hoverTable"><tr><th>Client</th><th>Address</th><th>City</th><th>State</th><th>Zip Code<br></th><th>Phone</th></tr>';


       // We have results! Go fetch rows!
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
            // This loop runs until there are no more results left to echo
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


         echo "<tr><td>" . $row["Client"]. "</td><td>" . $row["Address"]. "</td><td> " . $row["City"]. "</td><td> " . $row["State"]. "</td><td> " . $row["ZipCode"]. "</td><td> " . $row["Phone"]. "</td></tr>";

     }
     echo "</table>";

        }
    } else {
        // No results from query
        $message = "0 results";
    }

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
}
?>

</div>
</div>

<div class="center">

<?php

        if(isset($message)){ echo $message; }

    ?>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code is fetching the result rows twice, you will get inconsistent and missing results `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
            // This loop runs until there are no more results left to echo
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {`

Comment: Two points, not sure if this will fix the problem: first your close of the `</table>` is within the first `while` statement and secondly you seem to be using two functions that are going to return results from the database..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find, and you may disagree, but properly indenting your code as you go and opening and closing tags before filling in content help reduce the number of problems. Having said that now it'll probably not work!

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>db search</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <h2>Customer Search</h2>
            <p class="first">Search the Customer Database</p>

            <form action="searchcustomers.php" method="post">
              <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search...." />
              <input type="submit" value=">>" />
            </form>

            <?php
                $servername = "localhost";
                $username = "xxx";
                $password = "xxx";
                $dbname = "oldga740_SeniorProject";

                $conn = new mysqli( $servername, $username, $password, $dbname );
                if ( $conn->connect_error ) die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error );

                if( isset( $_POST['search'] ) ) {

                    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
                    $searchq = preg_replace( "#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchq );
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Customers` WHERE `Client` LIKE '%$searchq%';";

                    if ( $result = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql ) ) {
                        if ( mysqli_num_rows( $result ) > 0 ) {

                             echo '
                             <table class="hoverTable">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Client</th>
                                    <th>Address</th>
                                    <th>City</th>
                                    <th>State</th>
                                    <th>Zip Code</th>
                                    <th>Phone</th>
                                </tr>';

                                 while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
                                     echo "
                                     <tr>
                                        <td>".$row["Client"]."</td>
                                        <td>".$row["Address"]."</td>
                                        <td>".$row["City"]."</td>
                                        <td>".$row["State"]."</td>
                                        <td>".$row["ZipCode"]."</td>
                                        <td>".$row["Phone"]."</td>
                                    </tr>";
                                 }

                             echo '
                             </table>';

                        } else {
                            $message = "0 results";
                        }
                    }
                    mysqli_free_result( $result );
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="center">
        <?php if( isset( $message ) ){ echo $message; } ?>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually it seems to work perfectly.  Adding the if ( mysqli_num_rows( $result ) > 0 ) {
then echoing the table works.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad it helped - like I say, it's much easier to spot errors as you go with proper indentation ~ but then, I'm a Virgo and we tend to be picky about stuff like that '-)

Comment: I can't argue with you there.  Haha.  Thanks again and have a great night.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the redundant first while loop `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {`, if the query had just 1 result the first loop would have fetched it only while the 2nd while loop would have fetched nothing resulting in just a header and no body of the table.

```
<h2>Customer Search</h2>
<br>
<p class="first">Search the Customer Database</p>

<form action="searchcustomers.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search...." />
  <input type="submit" value=">>" />
</form>

<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "oldga740_SeniorProject";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


// If there is a search variable try to search database
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Client LIKE '%$searchq%'";

if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

     echo '<table class="hoverTable"><tr><th>Client</th><th>Address</th><th>City</th><th>State</th><th>Zip Code<br></th><th>Phone</th></tr>';


       // We have results! Go fetch rows!
            // This loop runs until there are no more results left to echo
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


         echo "<tr><td>" . $row["Client"]. "</td><td>" . $row["Address"]. "</td><td> " . $row["City"]. "</td><td> " . $row["State"]. "</td><td> " . $row["ZipCode"]. "</td><td> " . $row["Phone"]. "</td></tr>";

     }
     echo "</table>";


    } else {
        // No results from query
        $message = "0 results";
    }

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
}
?>

</div>
</div>

<div class="center">

<?php

        if(isset($message)){ echo $message; }

    ?>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I removed the redundant while loop, but now it's not returning "0 results" when I enter something that I know won't turn up in the search.

Comment: I just posted it for review

Comment: can you `echo mysqli_num_rows($result);` just after you run the query ? What count does it return ?

Comment: I dropped it in right after the while statement, but it didn't return anything

Comment: drop it right after `if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {`

Comment: I just did.  It didn't return anything

Comment: if it doesn't return anything, then your `if` condition would be false and it should say "0 results". there is something else going wrong... add an `else` to `if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {` and see if it is a query problem